# MySQL round in query, wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-5.5

I have a question about a query that I'm running on a MySQL Server (v5.5.50-0+deb8u1).

```
SELECT 12 - (SELECT qty FROM Table WHERE id = 5213) AS Amount
```

so Amount value is 12 - 8,5500000000000007 = 3.4499999999999993

But if I run the query:

```
 SELECT qty FROM Table WHERE id = 5213
```

it returns 8.55 that is the correct number written in the record, so I was expecting that the first querty returned 3.45.

The "qty" column in the table "Table" is a DOUBLE.

How is it possibile? How can I get the right answer from the query?
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating-point operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's [just the way floating numbers are](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html).

> Floating-point numbers sometimes cause confusion because they are
>   approximate and not stored as exact values. A floating-point value as
>   written in an SQL statement may not be the same as the value
>   represented internally.

This statement holds true for many programming languages as well. Some numbers don't even have an exact representation. Here's something from the [python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

> The problem is easier to understand at first in base 10. Consider the
>   fraction 1/3. You can approximate that as a base 10 fraction:
>
> 0.3 or, better,
>
> 0.33 or, better,
>
> 0.333 and so on. No matter how many digits you’re willing to write down, the result will never be exactly 1/3, but will be an
>   increasingly better approximation of 1/3.
>
> In the same way, no matter how many base 2 digits you’re willing to
>   use, the decimal value 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a base 2
>   fraction. In base 2, 1/10 is the infinitely repeating fraction

So in short generally doing is `float1 = float2` type of comparison is a bad idea but everyone keeps forgetting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define 'qty' column as decimal(10,2)